# Concatenating 2 basic strings together

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I have two strings:

```
string word;
string alphabet;
```

`word` has some input that I passed on to; let's say `"XYZ"`.

`alphabet` has the alphabet except `XYZ`, so it's `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW"`

When I tried to concat them with "+=", all I get is `word` (i.e. `"XYZ"`). I want to make it look like this:

```
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
```

What am I doing wrong? Code is basicly this vvvv

===========================encryption.cpp=================================================

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "encryption.h"
#include <string>

encryption::encryption()
{
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

}


string encryption::removeletter(string word,char letter)
{
    //remove letter
    string temp;
    int indis=0;
    for(int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] != letter)
            {
                temp[indis]=word[i] ;
                indis++;
            }

    }

    word=temp;

    return word;
}

This is the function i have proplems with :

    void encryption::encrypt(string word)//main.cpp is just calling this atm
    {
        string temp;
        int pos;
         //getting rid of the repeating letters
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if( (pos = temp.find(kelime[i])) < 0)
                temp += word[i];
        }
        word=temp;//that ends here
        //taking words letters out of the alphabet
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            alfabet=removeletter(alfabet,word[i]);

        }
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;alfabet[j] !='\0'; j++)
                if(alfabet[j+1] =='\0') alfabet[j]='\0';
        }

        /* I tried += here */
    }
```

===========================encryption.h====================================================

```
#ifndef encryption_h
#define encryption_h
#include<string>

    class encryption

    {
    public:
        encryption();

        void encrypt(string word);
        string removeletter(string word,char letter);
        //some other functions,i deleted them atm

    public:
            string alphabet;
            string encryptedalphabet;
            //staff that not in use atm(deleted)

    };

#endif
```

===========================main.cpp======================================================

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "encryption.h"
#include <string>

string word;
encryption encrypted;
cin>>word;
encrypted.encrypt( word);





 /****************************************************************************
orginalcode

**cikarmasifresi.cpp
****************************************************************************/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "cikarmasifresi.h"
#include <string>


using namespace std;

cikarmasifresi::cikarmasifresi()
{
alfabe = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

}



string cikarmasifresi::yazisifrele(string yazi)
{
    for(int j=0;yazi[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
            for(int i = 0; alfabe[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                if(yazi[j]==alfabe[i])
                {
                    yazi[j]=sifrealfabesi[i];
                }

            }
    }

    return yazi;
}
string cikarmasifresi::sifrecoz(string sifreliyazi)
{
    for(int j=0;sifreliyazi[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
            for(int i = 0; sifrealfabesi[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                if(sifreliyazi[j]==sifrealfabesi[i])
                {
                    sifreliyazi[j]=alfabe[i];
                }

            }
    }

    return sifreliyazi;
}
string cikarmasifresi::harfcikar(string kelime,char harf)
{
    //istenmiyen harfi cikar
    string temp;
    int indis=0;
    for(int i = 0; kelime[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(kelime[i] != harf)
            {
                temp[indis]=kelime[i] ;
                indis++;
            }

    }

    kelime=temp;

    return kelime;
}


void cikarmasifresi::sifrelialfabeolustur(string kelime)
{
    string temp,temp2;
    sifrekelimesi=kelime;

    int pos;
    for(int i = 0; i < kelime.length(); i++)
    {
        if( (pos = temp.find(kelime[i])) < 0)
            temp += kelime[i];
    }
    kelime=temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < kelime.length(); i++)
    {
        alfabe=harfcikar(alfabe,kelime[i]);

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < kelime.length()-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;alfabe[j] !='\0'; j++)
            if(alfabe[j+1] =='\0')  alfabe[j]='\0';

    }


     sifrealfabesi=kelime+alfabe;




        cout<<sifrealfabesi;

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; kelime[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout<<kelime[i];
    }






}





/****************************************************************************
** orginalcode

**cikarmasifresi.h
****************************************************************************/


#ifndef cikarmasifresi_h
#define cikarmasifresi_h
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class cikarmasifresi
{
public:
    cikarmasifresi();

    void sifrelialfabeolustur(string kelime);
    string yazisifrele(string yazi);
    string sifrecoz(string sifreliyazi);
    string harfcikar(string kelime,char harf);
public:
        string alfabe;
        string sifrealfabesi;
        string sifrekelimesi;

};

#endif





/****************************************************************************
 orginal code

**main.cpp
****************************************************************************/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "cikarmasifresi.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

        system("cls");
        string kelime,yazi,sifreli;
        cikarmasifresi sifrele;
        cout<<"********************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"sifre kelimesi gir :"<<endl;
        cin>>kelime;
        sifrele.sifrelialfabeolustur(kelime);/*
        cout<<"********************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Alfabe  :"<<sifrele.alfabe<<endl;
        cout<<"********************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sifreli Alfabe :"<<sifrele.sifrealfabesi<<endl;
        cout<<"********************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Cumle gir :"<<endl;
        cin>>yazi;

        cout<<"********************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sifre :"<< sifrele.yazisifrele(yazi)<<endl;
        cout<<"********************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"sifreli yazi gir :"<<endl;
        cin>>sifreli;
        cout<<"********************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sonuc :"<<sifrele.sifrecoz(sifreli)<<endl;

        */




}
```

Comment: `alphabet += word;` should work.

Comment: Have you tried `alphabet = word + alphabet;` ?

Comment: Also, when you enter code into a question, please use _copy-and-paste_ instead of rewriting it. In the code in your question you are using different spelling of `alphabet` and even spell it without the ending `t` in one case.

Comment: yep is there anything likestrcat i can use for them?

Comment: If it's not working, then please edit your question to include your _actual_ code before we can properly help you. Also please read about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If you have two std::string objects, you can use `+` to concatenate them.

Comment: whats `kelime[]` and also u seem to use `temp` which may be blank.

Comment: 'but it's not working' - I know I've said this before, but it's not working because you have a bug in your code somewhere. You need to find the bug. Not ask for some magic to make string concatenation work.

Comment: [`std::basic_string::operator+=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D).

Comment: @user2265881 If you post a complete program, and say what the inputs are, someone will take that program run it and tell you where the bug is. Don't post made up code, it's no help to anyone.

Comment: ok sorry about that i didnt wanna post it cuz you know its not english

Comment: @user2265881 Not being in English is not a problem, post the real code.

Comment: i did, should i delete the english version?

Comment: @user2265881 You've posted way too much code - please have a look at SSCCE as per Joachim's comment. Following this guidance makes it much easier for people to help you, and even better, you'll often solve the problem yourself in the process of doing it.

Comment: @JBentley but you guys insisted me to post the orginal program so i did, also there is english version, whitout it,it can be hard to understand ; which functions doing what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
string cikarmasifresi::harfcikar(string kelime,char harf)
{
    //istenmiyen harfi cikar
    string temp;
    int indis=0;
    for(int i = 0; kelime[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(kelime[i] != harf)
            {
                temp[indis]=kelime[i] ;
                indis++;
            }

    }

    kelime=temp;

    return kelime;
}
```

should be

```
string cikarmasifresi::harfcikar(string kelime,char harf)
{
    //istenmiyen harfi cikar
    string temp;
    int indis=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < kelime.length(); i++)
    {
        if(kelime[i] != harf)
            {
                temp[indis]=kelime[i] ;
                indis++;
            }

    }

    kelime=temp;

    return kelime;
}
```

kelime is a std::string. It doesn't have a null terminator like a C string.

These function are wrong in exactly the same way

```
string cikarmasifresi::sifrecoz(string sifreliyazi)

string cikarmasifresi::yazisifrele(string yazi)
```

A different error is this

```
string cikarmasifresi::harfcikar(string kelime,char harf)
{
    //istenmiyen harfi cikar
    string temp;
    int indis=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < kelime.length(); i++)
    {
        if(kelime[i] != harf)
            {
                temp[indis]=kelime[i] ;
                indis++;
            }

    }
    kelime=temp;
    return kelime;
}
```

`temp` is a zero length string so `temp[indis]` is an error. You probably meant `temp += kelime[i]` like this

```
string cikarmasifresi::harfcikar(string kelime,char harf)
{
    //istenmiyen harfi cikar
    string temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < kelime.length(); i++)
    {
        if(kelime[i] != harf)
            {
                temp += kelime[i];
                indis++;
            }

    }
    kelime=temp;
    return kelime;
}
```

This is a third error

```
for(int i = 0; i < kelime.length()-1; i++)
{
    for(int j=0;alfabe[j] !='\0'; j++)
        if(alfabe[j+1] =='\0')  alfabe[j]='\0';

}
```

I really don't know what you are trying to do here, so I can't suggest the fix. Maybe you should just delete this code.

Comment: Thank you for that john, but it didnt fix the problem

Comment: OK but I've found another problem see above. I'm still looking.

Comment: @user2265881 No problem, just post the real code straightaway next time.